# Расширение модели user. password, username

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста решить такую проблему

в django1.6 я расширил модель User следующим образом:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class UserProfile(User):    
   .........
........

    family = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
    )
    skype = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )
    email_address = models.EmailField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=True,
    )

    ........
........

    objects = UserManager()
```

в результате в административной панели появилась форма с указанными выше полями. после её заполнения данные помещаются в таблицу базы данных "[app_userprofile](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/up.png)". эта таблица связана с таблицей "[auth_user](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/au.png)" при помощи foreign key.

проблема в том что в таблице "auth_user" поля "username" и "password" пустые. но каждому пользователю они необходимы.

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы после регистрации нового пользователя(из админпанели и со страницы сайта) данные "username" и "password" попадали в таблицу "auth_user"

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить в `settings.py` строку `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.UserProfile'`

Вот тут вот более подробно: [ссылка](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/auth/customizing.html#auth-custom-user)

P.S. А вообще я бы на вашем месте использовал `AbstractUser`, как в [этом](http://djbook.ru/examples/47/) примере.